# Is it possible to create weblogic servers instances in java for testing?

Tags: java, api, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Is there any way to create weblogic servers and making mock objects or instances of that server in java for testing purposes?

What I mean is: 
To create/simulate a server from java, instead of actually hosting a server, so that it could be used for testing purposes

Comment: what do you mean by weblogic server instances? you mean multiple servers? if yes, why?

Comment: What I meant was to create/simulate a server from java, instead of actually hosting a server, so that it could be used for testing purposes?

Comment: What do you want to test with this server mock?

Comment: For example, I want to check if an application is deployed to a weblogic server which is hosted remotely. So just for running the test cases, if we could somehow simulate the weblogic server locally with the same configuration as that of the remote server?

This I think would help the test cases to run faster and will eliminate the need of connecting to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a mock.

You can use this library for it if I am not mistaken.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.fabric3.weblogic/fabric3-weblogic-mock